Notify contributors of a commitee terms changes
I'm designing a rotating savings feature where the admin inputs a monthly contribution amount and invites a set number of contributors, who can then choose to accept or decline within a set timeframe before the invitation expires.
When a contributor declines or their invitation expires, the total number of participants is reduced, which impacts the initial contribution amount set by the admin. This raises a few questions about the best approach:
Notification Strategy: Should remaining contributors be notified every time a participant declines or an invitation expires, or would this become overwhelming and lead to notification fatigue?
Adjusting Contribution Amounts: Should the contribution amount automatically adjust to cover the shortfall, knowing that remaining contributors might not be able to afford a higher monthly payment?
Cycle Start: Should the start of the savings cycle be paused until the necessary number of contributors is reached, allowing the admin to start the cycle manually once the group is complete?
Any input on best practices or similar approaches in other apps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Hello! Can you share more about the users? The context, and their motivation?
